# How to switch one page to another page using js?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know that how i call/switch one page to another page using javascript.

I am trying to creating a Game.
in which 2 slides. 
First Slides is for game overview in which there is a 
when i click on play button it should redirect me to second page. 
i want to know how it will work in JavaScript.Can't use html.
Here is my game link which i want to create.
https://www.screencast.com/t/qmbzE9nWei2c

Please watch this link and understand how it work and help me give me some tips.

Thanks

Comment: Set window.location.href to your next page's url.

Comment: location.href = "www.yoursite.com"; use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by simply adding an `onclick` event to the `button`:

```
<button onclick="location.href='www.example.com';"> Play </button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sidharth Gusain